# MS word 2013 Include picture - F9 does not refresh the pictures

Tags: ms-word, mergefield

I have this problem and have spent days googling for a solution with no success.

I am using the mailing to make several pages where its correspondent user picture is shown. Everything works fine to create it, for example, the code to show the picture is the following:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "c:\\fotos\\{MERGEFIELD fotoname MERGEFORMAT}"}
```

This is working fine, i just press <kbd>F9</kbd> key and it shows the pic. So far so good.

Then I press on Mailings, Finish & Merge, Edit Individual Documents and i print the rest of the documents with its corresponding data. Everything is fine, but the same picture is shown in all the documents.

So here comes the big problem: i select everything and then i press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all the pictures shown, but the picture stays the same anyway!!!

I check the source of the other pictures

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "c:\\fotos\\id_pict_nn.jpg"}
```

and it is fine, every picture has its own link, but the pictures are not refreshed after having selected everything and then pressed <kbd>F9</kbd>.

It only works if i select every picture and then press <kbd>F9</kbd>. But this is not the point, since they're more than 2000 documents and i don't have time to achieve this one by one.

Why isn't refreshing <kbd>F9</kbd> not working even if i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to select everything and the <kbd>F9</kbd> to make every picture be shown accordingly???

Please help!!!! How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

F9 only works on certain things, and I believe if it finds something it dosen't like it breaks everything.
I'm afraid you'll have to use a different method than F9.

Also, don't you mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything?

Comment: Oh no, in MS world, it is Ctrl + E. I know in other better worlds it is indeed Ctrl + A.

Comment: I'm sorry, you mean Microsoft Word 2013 right?  I doubt you mean this [link](http://www.msworld.org/) :).  And look under [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HA102748895.aspx) click the "show all" button and Ctrl+F for "CTRL+A"
If you have changed the hotkey, I recommend when posting you use the default one.

Comment: Yes, MS Word 2013 ;-) Sorry, i didn't know how to put the default one.

Comment: Ah, don't worry, and I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Ok, i could finally find out what was wrong: I was inserting the source or image link inside a textbox, and that was the problem. So i put the link of the image just like any other text (without frames or  textbox) and it finally worked by selecting all, and then pressing the F9 key to update the rest of the document!!! Hurrraaa!!! :) Thanks a lot for the help!!!!